# Prevent UISlider from firing UIControlEventValueChanged event when releasing thumb

Tags: objective-c, uislider

When observing the `UIControlEventValueChanged` event on a `UISlider`, I noticed that this event is again fired when releasing the thumb. I cannot circumvent this second firing via `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` since the value `UIControlEventValueChanged` event has already fired. Is there a way to prevent this second firing of `UIControlEventValueChanged` when releasing the thumb? Or is there a way to cancel all in progress touches on the slider?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? This is how sliders are supposed to work, and how users would expect them to work.

Comment: Just as a touch down doesn't register as a value change, I would assume a touch up would not be considered a value change. Somewhat like the audio player in iOS, the audio's position is only changed when dragging the thumb, not when releasing it. At the moment I'm implementing value changes within `UIControlEventTouchDragInside | UIControlEventTouchDragOutside`to implement the desired behavior, still testing if there's any unwanted side effects.

Comment: I assume you're using the slider in continuous mode, so you get a continuous stream of calls to the action method. I don't understand why one more call (on the touch up) makes any difference. BTW, when I test this, I do register a value change on touch down.

Comment: You are right, I must have missed the initial touch down value change with the army of log messages firing at me. I guess the `UIControlEventValueChanged` behavior encompasses the down, drag, and up events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When observing the `UIControlEventValueChanged` event, touch-downs->drags->touch-ups are received.

When needing to captures these events separately I had to observe:
`UIControlEventTouchDown` -> `UIControlEventTouchDragInside | UIControlEventTouchDragOutside` -> `UIControlEventTouchUpInside | UIControlEventTouchUpOutside`